# Errors in building a RSS XML in Windows Using Word Pad

Tags: xml, windows, rss, wordpad

I am trying to build a XML Rss feed using Word Pad in windows.  The issue I get is that it gives me this message when I attempt to view in Firefox:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

The link to it is http://cursosbiblicos.net/app/AudioXml/Efesios.xml

The text from Word Pad was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><channel><atom:link href="http://www.cursosbiblicos.net/efesios.xml" type="application/rss+xml" rel="self"/><lastBuildDate>Tue, 9 Apr 2013 09:26:14 -0500</lastBuildDate><link>http://www.cursosbiblicos.net</link><description>efesios XML</description><language>en</language><copyright>2013 Cursos Biblicos</copyright><item><description> Efesios1:1-4 </description><link> http://cursosbiblicos.net/cursos/mp3streamer/files/1EF%201.1-4%20Los%20Escogidos.mp3</link></item><item><description> Efesios1:4-5 </description><link> http://cursosbiblicos.net/cursos/mp3streamer/files/2EF%201.4-5%20La%20Predestinacion.mp3</link></item><item><description> Efesios1:5-6 </description><link> http://cursosbiblicos.net/cursos/mp3streamer/files/3EF%201.5-6%20Para%20Alabanza%20de%20la%20Gloria%20de%20Su%20Gracia.mp3</link></item><item><description> Efesios1:7-8 </description><link> http://cursosbiblicos.net/cursos/mp3streamer/files/4EF%201.7-8%20La%20Redencion.mp3</link></item><item><description> Efesios1:9-10 </description><link> http://cursosbiblicos.net/cursos/mp3streamer/files/5EF%201.9-10%20El%20Proposito%20Eterno%20de%20Dios.mp3</link></item><channel></rss>
```

However, at the beginning after I save it, it adds:

```
turnerc23turnerc23212013-04-22T01:31:00Z2013-04-22T01:31:00Z13411945Toshiba164228212
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you are seeing is just a warning that browsers tend to give you when you look at an XML document rather than the usual HTML document. The XML document should be shown below the warning, but in your case it looks like your XML document is empty.

It would be helpful if you showed us your WordPad XML document.

**Edit:**

It would appear that WordPad is a rich text editor and so it is adding it's own formatting info to your document. You do not want that.

Use a plain text editor instead eg. Windows Notepad.

Comment: see above in the OP for more details